# Lexical or preprocessor issue in react native while building ios app <React/RCTUtils.h> not found

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

[image]When I am trying to build my ios app in xcode, the build is failing due to lexical or preprocessor issue the error shows up like this

[image: error image]

Comment: Haha! I am one of the two react-native-device-info maintainers, currently fuzz-busting our XCode warnings and I googled this one only to land...here. About this error but in my library, with no answer. I will update this as soon as I find an answer :-)

Comment: I believe there is something wrong in the .xcproj for the react-native-device-info framework / header search paths but I have not been able to cleanly pin it down yet.  When building within a normal project this does not stop build though. @asim-dahal are you currently blocked on this project or is the app itself building despite the detected issue in XCode?

Comment: We have a pull request going that will fix this issue. It is a header paths problem, and is specific to this library, it is not your project's problem.

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, please accept it

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem specific to the react-native-device-info module.

For your specific case you may try [v1.6.1 or higher (currently at 2.0 as of May 21, 2019) of the library](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info/releases/tag/v1.6.1) and that should fix things for you.

For others interested more generally in the problem, this is a react-native library that uses native code, so it has an XCode project embedded within it for use in react-native after you run `react-native link react-native-device-info`. Unfortunately, the library was not including any directories in it's header search path, so it was of course unable to find the header files for the react-native objects it was using locally.

A library user [proposed a change that fixed that problem for tvOS](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info/pull/652/commits/90494fe1ed063a8f4731d371dccb3de32b153a54), and I [extended the change to cover iOS](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info/pull/652/commits/8bb7a9f2ee3bbefbc6bb9265454aa7c7897704ab) as well, and now the library no longer generates errors like this for iOS or tvOS targets.

Perhaps someone with a similar issue may find the specific changes required for the fix useful in their projects

Comment: Tried 1.6.1 and still having the same error as OP. See more details on [github PR discussion](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info/pull/652#issuecomment-488638072)

Comment: works if I remove `use_frameworks!` flag from the podfile.

Comment: Using 1.6.1 and the error persists. Using or not using `use_frameworks!` still has a failing build. Is there a lower version of the library which currently works?

Comment: Strange, I will say that use_frameworks in general is problematic with react-native so you should avoid it if possible. I have heard that switching to legacy build system can sometimes get the build to work even if you must have use_frameworks! - we have not had any reports of failure yet though, I encourage you to participate in the linked github PR discussion and post package.json dependencies + Podfiles (if using pods), we are actively working to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @RichardMcCluskey are you still having a problem? We are at 2.0 on the device-info package now and I am not aware of any open github issues related

Comment: @MikeHardy Unfortunately I am still having this problem on device-info v2.2.2 and RN 0.58.6